# Taking into account

Tags: word-order

Which one is right?

"This paper modifies an optimal income taxation model and derives the optimal rates that **take into account pollution**."

or

" This paper modifies an optimal income taxation model and derives the optimal rates that **take pollution into account**."

Answer (score 1):

I would say both are permissable but option 2 reads better.